# Duplicate Google cloud message account registered when app re-install

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, messaging, message, amazon-sns

I am working on integrate GCM to the android app, my working flow is first whenever the user enter the app, it check whether the share pref. has the gcm id, if not , then reg and save to share pref.

The problem is, it seems the id is duplicate after I install the app again. For example, if I install three times, then the app will receive three times of the message.

As I am using Amazon SNS service , the GCM id is store in their database, how can I handle the case of user re-install the app to prevent register again?

Thanks

```
if (gs.settings.getString("endpoint_arn", "").equals("")) {
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
    asnsc = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(Constant.id,Constant.secret));
    asnsc.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1));
    asnsc.setEndpoint("sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com");

    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {
            try {
                CreatePlatformEndpointRequest per = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
                per.setToken(gcm.register(Constant.projectID));
                per.setPlatformApplicationArn(Constant.platformARN);
                CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = asnsc.createPlatformEndpoint(per);
                String arn = result.getEndpointArn();
                gs.editor.putString("endpoint_arn", arn).commit();
     }
}
```

Comment: why you dont unreg it before getting new id?

Comment: Thanks for helping , how can  I check whether the phone has install the app and reg before? using the gcm.register(Constant.projectID) to unreg?

Comment: that means, how can I get endpoint when I enter the app? thanks

Comment: just call gcm.unregister() before you register the new id

Comment: thanks , I am going to test that

Comment: if putting  gcm.unregister(); before, it reg 2 times and receive message three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for these 3 steps in order to set up everything working:

- Firstly unregister the old registration id before you register the new id as mentioned in the comments.
- Secondly, when you unregister, you should send the old registration ID to your server and remove it from your database.
- If after registering and getting the new registration ID you send a message with the old registration ID, Google will respond you with a new registration id. This response indicates that your server should delete the old registration ID and use only the new one.

Answer (score 0):

(Assume that your server had subscribed SNS EndpointUpdated Event)

When you send the message by old registration id, it will trigger SNS changed the old registration id to new registration id in Aws SNS database which you check in the SNS console.
In the same time, the SNS will send you a feedback about EndpointUpdated. 
Using the endpoint arn in the feedback, you can check the token of the endpoint. The token of the endpoint in AWS database is different from your database, you can delete_endpoint in AWS and also delete the device record in your database. So you can clean up the database.

However, there is a potential problem of above practice. In case, you failed to receive the feedback. You will still send duplicate notifications to users. I still figuring out how to deal with it. lol

According to [Amazon SNS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/):

> How does SNS Mobile Push handle token feedback from notification services?
>
> SNS Mobile Push automatically handles token feedback services on your behalf, and exposes the feedback information via events published to a topic you may choose to consume. This approach reduces the operational burden of sending push notifications, and maximizes the speed and reliability with which your notifications are delivered. Push notifications services such as APNS and GCM provide feedback about tokens which may have expired or been replaced by new tokens. When a particular token is replaced by a new token, SNS automatically updates the associated endpoint, and notifies you via an event. When a particular token expires, perhaps because a user deleted your app, SNS marks the endpoint as disabled and notifies you via an event. You don’t strictly need to consume the feedback notifications in order to send push notifications with SNS, but may choose to do so based on your broader use case.